# Microsoft Bot Builder with .NET 4.5?

Tags: .net, nuget, botframework

I am trying to install the Microsoft Bot Builder nuGet package to a project that targets .NET framework 4.5. When I click install, I get the following error:

`Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder 3.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

Is there any version of the Bot Builder package that is compatible with .NET version 4.5? Or am I out of luck and have to change the target framework of my applicaton?

Comment: You'll have to target 4.6 to keep it happy.  I suppose you could retrieve an older version of package.  Hmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last version of the framework that supported 4.5 was `1.1.0`, after that version the framework only targeted .NET 4.6.

You can do the command

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Bot.Builder -Version 1.1.0
```

and that will install that version, or you can change your project to use .NET 4.6, or [compile it from source](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/releases) and see if you can get it to compile under .NET 4.5.